# Rails 4 form without model and database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a form in HAML, but I don't have a model or database table. The form should just send its fields via `POST` to an action and I will handle it from there.
As far as I could tell, `form_for` has to have a `record`.

What is the current best practice to do this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`form_for` can also take an arbitrary symbol:

```
<%= form_for :anything, url: "my_controller/my_action" do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit  %>
<% end  %>
```

This will send a post to `my_controller/my_action`.

The html output will look something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="my_controller/my_action" method="post">
    <input id="anything_name" name="anything[name]" type="text">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save Testing">
</form>
```

Comment: Can I just fill something in, that doesn't have to exist?

Comment: yep, the symbol will just be used to group the inputs together.

Comment: & form will keep its data in case of redder on error?